# Neo4J to accept both local and non-local connections?

Tags: neo4j

When I uncomment

`dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0`

in `neo4j.conf` in my Neo4J 3.3.3 database, I allow it accept non-local connections. However, in this case it doesn't seem to accept anymore the `localhost` ones. Is it possible to set it up to accept both `localhost` and nonlocal connections, such as `0.0.0.0` above?